# MongoDB `compact` command taking very long to run

Tags: mongodb

So my database stores scraped pages in a MongoDB, with each document representing a page. The `text` field contains the raw scraped HTML of the page, and that field for each document is by far the largest.

Recently, I migrated all of the `text` fields into new documents on a separate disk in order to reduce the storage size on my first disk (the first disk was full). Once that was finished, I recently ran the compact command:

```
db.runCommand({compact: MyCollection})
```

The collection is ~920GB in storage space and the command has been running for about 5 days. The storage space on the disk is the same as it was when I started running the command.

Is this run-time expected, or is there something wrong?

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is the result of `db.currentOp()`, of which I extracted the op in question and replaced appropriate fields with dummy names:

```
        "desc" : "conn1633",
        "threadId" : "140449553991424",
        "connectionId" : 1633,
        "client" : "MyHostAddress",
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : 62523682,
        "secs_running" : 492701,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("492701361739"),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "db.MyCollection",
        "query" : {
            "compact" : "MyCollection"
        },
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "w",
            "Database" : "W"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1),
                    "w" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have never ran this, but the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#blocking) mention "Only use compact during scheduled maintenance periods." which leads me to believe it probably shouldn't take that long. Also from docs: "You may view the intermediate progress either by viewing the mongod log file or by running the db.currentOp() in another shell instance."

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited the original comment with the output of `db.currentOp()` (filtered by the op in question). Additionally, the log file doesn't seem to display the progress, just the original command entered.

Comment: I was expecting an `inprog.progress` key as shown [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#output-example). Could you have missed it out?

Comment: I just checked again, however there is no `.progress` key. The object I pasted in the original comment was one object within the `inprog` list. I'll play around with the filters available and see if I can get it to be displayed.

Comment: What is your specific version of MongoDB server (as reported by `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell)? Are you using the default storage engine?

Comment: My `db.version()` is `3.2.17`, and I'm using the default WiredTiger storage engine.

Comment: Update: It's still running over 1 month later...

Comment: @Matt Did you find the solution?